# How can i compare fields in firebase with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a chat app and I'm trying to build a screen with the user history conversations with other users.
So basically what I am trying to do is taking all the values in the message field map (just the values, not the keys) like shown here:  [image]
And I want to compare it with  the docs in the chatRoom like shown here: [image]

If I compare them and the result came as true, I want to show the user the data that inside that chatRoom.
I'm really struggling to understand how to compare them
Thanks in advance.

Edit: here is the code:

```
  final String chatId;
  Chat({this.chatId});
  @override
  _ChatState createState() => _ChatState();
}

class _ChatState extends State<Chat> {
  // Our own id
  final String currentUserId = auth.currentUser?.uid;

  // Loading state
  bool isLoading = false;

  // Query variable
  Future<QuerySnapshot> chatHistoryResults;

  // All the user rooms will be in this variable
  List<String> roomsUserList = [];

  // All the chat rooms will be in this variable
  List<String> roomsChatList = [];

  // All the history chat tickets will be here.
  List<QuerySnapshot> tickets = [];

  // Getting all the current user rooms in a list of Id rooms.
  //TODO: fix the chat history
  getRooms() async {
    roomsUserList = [];
    //roomsChatList = [];
    DocumentSnapshot myDocUser = await userRef.doc(currentUserId).get();
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> userRoomsMap = await myDocUser.get('messages');
    userRoomsMap.forEach((key, value) {
      roomsUserList.add(value);
    });
    print(roomsUserList);
    roomsUserList.forEach((element) async {
      String chatDoc = chatRef.doc(element).get().toString();
      roomsChatList.add(chatDoc.toString());
    });
    print(roomsChatList);
  }

  // Build the story tickets here
  buildStoryTickets() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: chatRef.get().then((snapshot) {
        snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {});
      }),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<AuthService>(
      create: (context) => AuthService(),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[350],
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(55.0),
          child: Header(
            title: 'Chat',
          ),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            //buildStoryTickets(),
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: FlatButton(onPressed: () {
                getRooms(); // Just to check 
              }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I manage to insert all the values from the "messages" map inside a List called "roomUserList"

Comment: Please share the code where you are trying to compare, it'll be easier to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get the all the data from the User and chat room Using the StreamBuilder.
Once you have the messages and Chat room you can compare it by developing code logic.

PFB sample code to get data from firestore:

```
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _firestore.collection('users').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  //add your comparison logic here
                  );
                }
```